# Get Albums and Photos of specified albums using flickr api

Tags: flickr

I want to get photos from albums which I have on flickr . I have 4 albums . Curently I am doing flickr.people.getPublicPhotos method which returns all photos . Here is my url

https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=[]&user_id=[]&format=json";

How do I get photos via albums of flickr is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [flickr.photosets.getPhotos](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html).  Pass the ID of your photoset; receive a list of the photos in that photoset (their IDs and titles).

Comment: how to get the photoset id?

Comment: The photoset id is in the album URL -https://www.flickr.com/photos/USERNAME/albums/PHOTOSET_ID